# What's his horse name?

Tags: riddle, knowledge, lateral-thinking, metapuzzles

You're an adventurer looking for treasures.

During one of your journeys, you encounter a knight riding a horse who agrees to tell you informations about a huge treasure he has heard of.

Only if you're able to find his horse's name, he also gave you clues for each letters.

> "1st letter : It's the 1st letter of what he said."
>
> "2nd letter : Well ... I can't give you a letter for this one, but i'm sure you'll find a way to guess it."
>
> "3rd letter : It's the fifth letter of what he gave to you."
>
> "4th letter : It's the 2nd letter of what she was doing."

**So, what's his horse name ?**

**And also, can you guess it's color ?**

Hint 1 :

> There's a reason why there are only 4 letters in his horse's name

Hint 2 :

> You've already met this knight before

Hint 3 :

> There is a reason to why all his verbs are in the past

Hint 4 :

> You could ask hexomino to help you find the 3rd letter

Comment: Literally, W*HH. Doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier, indeed you're totally off track, I'll add a few hints later in the afternoon. The "lateral-thinking" tag is essential here.

Comment: For the fourth letter, does "she" refer to someone other than the knight?

Comment: @Elpharya Of couse, and by the way, the knight says everything that is inside the quotes, so the "he", may not refer to the knight as well.

Comment: Chess, seasons, Alice in Wonderland.. so many thoughts but no way to get any to really fit.

Comment: @mkinson the tag "knowledge" doesn't refere to this kind of knowledge, you just need an internet connexion and you have to be curious.

Comment: Based on the answers you said to be correct, I would suggest the use of 'meta-puzzle' tag.

Comment: @Annosz Yes, you're right, i just thaught that it would give too much information, but now that the answer is almost found, i can indeed add it.

Comment: KevinT gor the right answer, but congratulations to Fifth_H0r5eman, CinCout and Soltius, for finding all these informations ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Deriving from [Fifth_H0r5eman](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43311/fifth-h0r5eman)'s and [CinCout](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/5116/cincout)'s answers, I adapted the second `letter', to fit the description of it being not a letter.

Name:

> DANY

"1st letter : It's the 1st letter of what he said."

> He refers to the Frenchman in one of your question `What will the Frenchman say?' . Since he said D (for Dimanche) as mentioned in the answer, the first letter is "D".

"2nd letter : Well ... I can't give you a letter for this one, but I'm sure you'll find a way to guess it."

> "A", comming from the sequence number A033420, which is the answer in your question `Find the next number in this sequence'

"3rd letter : It's the fifth letter of what he gave to you."

> A "Green Tick" was the answer and given to the man in your third question, solved by Hexomino (Hint #4), giving us "N"

"4th letter : It's the 2nd letter of what she was doing."

> The ant in the fourth question was "Lying", giving us "Y"

Color (adapted from [Soltius](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37736/soltius)):

> Green, as visible in your profile picture.

Comment: rot13(Gur 2aq yrggre lbh tnir vfa'g n yrggre (fvapr vg'f n ahzore), ohg lbh'er nyzbfg gurer, punatr vg, naq lbh'yy trg gur obhagl ;) )

Comment: Next guess, based on the same question for letter 2.

Comment: You got it, but : rot13(Gur frpbaq yrggre jnf na N, orpnhfr gur nafjre gb gur chmmyr jnf 1, juvpu yrnqf gb gur 1fg yrggre bs gur nycunorg : N, ohg V fgvyy inyvqngrq lbhe nafjre, gb qba'g fcraq gbb zhpu gvzr ba guvf cbvag.)

Answer (score 15):

I don't know if I am an adventurer looking for treasures but I know that:

> **“I'm an adventurer, looking for treasure”** is a quote by Paulo Coelho in his book **"The Alchemist"**.This book tells about a shepherd boy named Santiago  who dreams a dream that according to the meaning of the fortune-teller hints at a treasure, the boy looks for the treasure and meets his way people who help him on his way to the treasure that was eventually found at the starting point of the boy which is supposed to explain to us that first of all we must search close to us And not far away.

**line 1:**

> "1st letter : It's the 1st letter of what he said."

means:

> the old king named Melchizedek said to Santiago :"**I**t is what you have always wanted to accomplish. Everyone, when they are young, knows what their Personal Legend is"-1st:**I** letter

**line 2:**

> "2nd letter : Well ... I can't give you a letter for this one, but i'm sure you'll find a way to guess it."

means:

> I guess is:**r**

**line 3:**

> "3rd letter : It's the fifth letter of what he gave to you."

means:

> pers**o**nal legend -the old king named Melchizedek introduces the idea of a Personal Legend-5rd letter :**o**

**line 4:**

> "4th letter : It's the 2nd letter of what she was doing."

means:

> she is the Romani fortune teller in a nearby town and what she did was i**n**terpret the Santiago's dream -2nd letter:**n**

the answer is:

> **his horse name: Iron , it's color:** I guess is **gold**(Because the alchemists are involved in making gold from Iron )

Comment: Wow this answer is really interesting (and a little far-fetched), but sorry this isn't the right answer. First of all, because I had no idea about this book, then there is a logical way to find the 2nd letter, not just trying to make a real word with the remaining letters. And I think alchemists turned plumb into gold, not iron. Nevertheless, i congratulate you for your answer, it was really interesting ;) .

Answer (score 7):

After some hints in the below comments, I believe the answer is:

> Dany

Because:

> Each letter refers to one of your past puzzles (Hint #1, there is a reason there are only 4 letters)

"1st letter : It's the 1st letter of what he said."

> From your question "What will the Frenchman say?", the Frenchman said "D"

"2nd letter : Well ... I can't give you a letter for this one, but i'm sure you'll find a way to guess it."

> From OPs question "Find the next number in this sequence", the answer was not a letter, but a number: 1. Converting this to a letter gives us "A"

"3rd letter : It's the fifth letter of what he gave to you."

> A "Green Tick" was the answer and given to the man in your third question, solved by Hexomino (Hint #4), giving us "N"

"4th letter : It's the 2nd letter of what she was doing."

> The ant in the fourth question was "Lying", giving us "Y"

As for the colour, I'd say:

> Green, and you are the rider, since your profile picture is of yourself ridy a tiny green horse (Credit to Soltius here, I hadn't noticed OP's Profile picture)

Comment: rot13(Lbh'er nyzbfg gurer, bayl gur 1fg naq 2aq yrggref ner jebat, lbh pna thrff gur 2aq yrggre gur fnzr jnl lbh thrffrf gur bguref. Purpx ntnva gur pyhrf gur xavtug tnir lbh sbe gurfr yrggref.)

Comment: I'm just struggling to guess No# 2 now, as none sound particularly more like names to me :p

Comment: Take a closer look to what you said in your "Because" paragraph, then see how you guessed letters 3 and 4 and do the same for letters 1 and 2 ;)

Answer (score 6):

This is my first try here :)

The first letter is

> "F" the first thing the knight says is "First letter"

The second letter is

> "I" I guessed based on the other letters

The third letter is

> "S" because he gave you "Clues"

The fourth letter is

> "H" because it is the second letter in "What she was doing"

So, his name is

> fish?

Comment: This is what I got, about a minute after you!

Comment: Probably "what she was doing" isn't meant this way. Since "she" can't refer to the knight, I only see one other being that it could refer to.

Comment: Rémi said that I was totally off track, so apparently your reason for 4 is wrong.

Comment: Welcome to the **Puzzling Stack Exchange (PSE)**! Since you are new to this site and community, I suggest that you visit the [*Help Center*](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help), but I won't fully recommend it because you know how to write a good answer (so chances are, you have already viewed it); and you have over $1$k reputation on another stack exchange site, so you will likely become familiar with this environment. You may head [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) to learn particularly about asking questions, but apart from that, hope you enjoy! Happy Puzzling!! :D

Comment: Hi, nice try, I didn't realise that this kind of combinaison could turn into a real name ;) . But sorry this isn't the right way to think as @ArnaudMortier said. As you can see, the knight says "HE", so he doesn't refere to himself while saying this.

Answer (score 3):

Very partial guess, but would the knight be

> OP ? (we've "already met him before", + Hint 4 seems to point at PSE users)

and so

> based on OP's profile picture where he's "riding" a "horse", I'd say the horse's color is **green**.

Comment: Nice, keep going and i'm sure you'll find the right answer ;)

Comment: Have to work now, but I hope this will inspire fellow puzzlers!

Answer (score 3):

Deriving from [Fifth_H0r5eman](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43311/fifth-h0r5eman)'s [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/81639/5116):

Name:

> DENY (although I am not sure why will someone name their horse that!)

"1st letter : It's the 1st letter of what he said."

> He refers to the Frenchman in this [question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/80782/5116). Since he said D (for Dimanche) as mentioned in the [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/80783/5116), the first letter is "D".

"2nd letter : Well ... I can't give you a letter for this one, but I'm sure you'll find a way to guess it."

> "E", which makes the name "Deny", which is exactly what you're doing to us: denying the second letter ("I can't give you a letter for this one")

The following is lifted from Fifth_H0r5eman's answer:

"3rd letter : It's the fifth letter of what he gave to you."

> A "Green Tick" was the answer and given to the man in your third question, solved by Hexomino (Hint #4), giving us "N"

"4th letter : It's the 2nd letter of what she was doing."

> The ant in the fourth question was "Lying", giving us "Y"

Color:

> Green, as visible in your profile picture.

Comment: rot13(Lbhe frpbaq yrggre vfa'g rknpgyl gur evtug nafjre. Lbh'er bar yrggre pybfr gb gur obhagl, xrrc tbvat ;) )

Comment: @RémiHenry rot13(Hcqngrq gb tvir n shaavre nafjre ;) )

Comment: rot13(Sbe gur frpbaq bar V fnvq gung V pna'g tvir lbh n yrggre, ohg znlor lbh pna unir fbzrguvat ryfr gb svaq gur yrggre)

Answer (score 2):

The "He" is the OP.

First letter is

> "W" from What's from the OP question, "What's his horse name?"

Second letter is

> "I" (guess, and because "I" can't give you a letter for this "one" - roman numeral)

Third letter is

> "L" since the OP gave us a "puzzle".

Fourth letter refers to a "she".. I'm going to make a huge leap and say that's the

> horse. If so she was carrying a rider, so "A"

Which makes the name

> WILA..

BUT why 4 letters in the name, how does that connect with the puzzle?
Already met the knight!?
Verbs in past tense?
These points make this answer not likely, but time's ticking on the Bounty so any guess is better than none.

Comment: Hi, nice try, but as you said there's still a lot of shady parts to your answer. But all I can say is that you're on the right path ;) .

Answer (score 2):

> I think the name of the horse is Time.
>
> T is the first letter of Treasure
> I -- "I'm sure you'll--"
> M fits the clue
> E just fits
> Who's the knight- Grandfather, father, myself-? Someone else?

Comment: Sorry but you're wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is

> DENY

and the color is

> Green

Explanation:

> This is a meta puzzle based on the OP's activity on this website, specifically to puzzles posted by the OP.

"1st letter : It's the 1st letter of what he said."

> It's referring to the puzzle [What will the Frenchman say?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/80782/17494). In the correct answer, the Frenchman said "Dimanche". First letter "D".

"2nd letter : Well ... I can't give you a letter for this one, but i'm sure you'll find a way to guess it."

> Maybe, the fact that the knight is "denying" me the second letter makes sense.

"3rd letter : It's the fifth letter of what he gave to you."

> It's referring to the puzzle [What is the reward?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/79910/17494). The correct answer was "Green tick". Fifth letter is a "N".

"4th letter : It's the 2nd letter of what she was doing."

> It's referring to the puzzle [3 ants walking in the desert](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/79673/17494). "She" is the third ant which, in the correct answer, is "lYing". Second letter is an "Y".

Color:

> The OP is riding a green horse in his picture. He is the knight in this riddle. Credit to user [Soltius](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/81637/17494)

Comment: Well, some explanations will be needed if you want your answer to be validated ;)

Comment: @RémiHenry I was just adding the explanation. I hope this is it!

Comment: You're on the right path, but only your 3rd letter is correct (including the horse's color), you're almost there keep going ;)

Comment: @RémiHenry I think I got it now. See edited answer

Comment: I just noticed the answer from @KevinT. To be honest, I didn't base my answer on his, but it's fair that he is credited because he got most of the clues right before me.